# Why First Responder of secondary ViewConrollers do not show main ViewController methods?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a method on my main ViewController, like this:

```
@IBAction func sendData(_ button: MyButtonClass) {
self.doSomethingWithMy(button)
}
```

This view Controller is the main one. It is embedded in a NavigationController that is the initial one.

Inside this main ViewController I have a ViewContainer that leads to a secondary ViewController.

I am trying to make the buttons I have inside this secondary View Controller to run the `sendData` method that is inside the main ViewController.

For that matter, I try to drag the button to the First Responder of the secondary View Controller but the `sendData` method is not there. In fact Xcode does not even let me drag that and shows no list. Apparently that secondary view controller is not in the responder chain.

Isn't it supposed to be?

Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface Builder knows nothing of the responder chain. The First Responder proxy lists only existing UIResponder methods. To make a nil targeted action that will walk up the responder chain looking for a method to call, add your method selector manually to the First Responder proxy (using the Plus button) and now form the connection, working entirely in the view controller where the button is.

Comment: Brilliant. The most strange thing is that the First Responder, if selected individually, shows a lot of methods there but Xcode will not allow the button to be dragged to there. Simply brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I need not mention that the selector here is the Objective C selector and getting it right is up to you. If you don’t, the button will do nothing.